# ELM Custom Elements

Tags: elm, custom-element

I have the following ELM view element:

```
Html.node "test-elem" 
 [ Attributes.attribute "data-count" (model.count |> String.fromInt) ]
 []
```

test-elem is a custom html element:

```
 constructor() {
        super();
        this.me = this;
    }
    connectedCallback() {
        console.info(this.dataset.count);
        this.div = document.createElement("div");
        this.appendChild(this.div);
        this.div.innerText = "" + this.dataset.count;
    }

   attributeChangedCallback() {
        console.info(this.dataset.count);

        this.div.innerText = "" + this.dataset.count;
    }
```

If model.count changes the custom element does not get regenerated. How do I force this?

https://ellie-app.com/6SRrZjCzwfra1

Edited with suggestions from @Robin, but no luck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't see any problems with your Elm code, I think this is a problem with your custom element definition in JavaScript.

I'm not familiar with the custom elements API, but looking at your code (reproduced below):

```
customElements.define('test-elem', class TestElem extends HTMLElement {

        constructor() {
            super();
            this.me = this;
        }
        connectedCallback() {
            console.info(this.dataset.count);
            var div = document.createElement("div");
            this.appendChild(div);
            div.innerText = "" + this.dataset.count;
        }
    });
```

and the [MDN documentation for custom elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements), it's apparent that you should change the `connectedCallback` method to `attributeChangedCallback`. The reason being that Elm uses a virtual DOM and makes the fewest actual DOM updates possible when your model changes. In particular, when the count changes it won't remove the custom element from the DOM and add a new one, it will just change the appropriate attribute. It seems that your `connecedCallback` won't therefore be called, but `attributeChangedCallback` should be.

Also, as @Murdock correctly observed (by reading the MDN article, specifically the "Using the lifecycle callbacks" section, better than me), the `data-count` attribute has to be explicitly set to be observed, by using the `observedAttributes` getter, as follows:

```
static get observedAttributes() {
    return ['data-count'];
}
```

Comment: Ah wow. Ok I've updated my code but I still don't get the right behavior.

Comment: It never hits attributeChangedCallback

Comment: Oh ok, I was unable to test it but was pretty sure this would work. Not sure what else to suggest.

Comment: Adding observedAttributes fixed my issue.

    static get observedAttributes() {
        return ['data-count'];
    }

Comment: Thanks, and well done for solving it. I have edited my answer.

Comment: This diagram helps in understanding what is happening: https://andyogo.github.io/custom-element-reactions-diagram/